# Are too many badges on question review the cause of a huge closed votes queue?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review, badges, vote-to-close

I am wondering if badges on question reviews are the cause of the huge closed votes queue.
Shouldn't this be discussed or tested to see if the CV queue can be reduced **eliminating** some of the relevant badges?

On the other hands, I have seen several posts and opinions on Meta pointing to the opposite cause (too many badges) as reason for the increasing of the queue.
Too many 
**Edit**
[List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/badge-request?page=7&sort=votes&pagesize=50) of question proposing badges not really appreciated by the community

Comment: I don't see why the existence of the badges should grow the CV queue.  Flag queue during winterfest, yes; but the CV queue would be if anything helped by more attention via badges.  Most CV queue elements exist because one person casts a CV on a question in a low-activity tag and too few other people read that tag to see it.

Comment: The result is interesting. I have seen many question collecting minus because of proposed new badges for moderation. But looks like also the opposite is not appreciated.

Comment: Minus here is basically just 'disagreement', I wouldn't say 'unappreciated'.  Ideas on both sides dealing with the topic are likely to end up net minus - the reason we have a problem is, in large part, because it's not easy to solve, and the odds are most relatively simple solutions have been considered already.

Answer (score 9):

The badges don't really have any effect on the *size* of the queue. Some people think that more badges would cause users to participate more in the queue (and thus help reduce its size), but that would only be a temporary fix if it worked at all.

The badges more affect the *quality* of the reviews in the queues - the claim is that people who care about the review don't so much care about the badges, and people who care about the badges don't so much care about the review. The claim has for the most part held true. We see a lot of very crappy reviews from people who are just flying through them for the gold badge.

Comment: So, with your last sentence you basically agree with me in some way.

Comment: I'm trying to get you to realize that the badges only *indirectly* affect the size, and the size definitely is **not** our concern with the badges. The review quality is much more important. More badges will lower our review quality, which is already lower than desired from the *current* badges. Adding more makes no sense.

Comment: I agree this is why in my post I said that they should be less.

Comment: That's not at all clear in your question. You seem to want to discuss *if* badges affect the size of the queue. I say they barely do - they more affect the quality.

Comment: @animuson ♦ "The badges don't really have any effect on the size of the queue" Are you serious? So, If SO not offered a badge for - lets say - how many post you have edited, it would be the same? Like "Strunk and White"? Try to explain, why and how the 120k close-vote hump on SO not have a correlation to badges. I can only speak for myself. After being degraded, scorned and mocked here on meta, I have no lust what so ever to handle close votes ever more. I reached the Staward badge, 1000 edits, and was willing to go for nothing - but your answers here on meta made me to loose my interest. If y

Comment: Look, @david: if you start calling folks "fascists" because they disagree with you, you're gonna have to get used to your comments being deleted. This sort of childish behavior is not tolerated here.